# Changing specific 'properties' of a longtable

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

I want to set some general properties for my `longtable` so that their top row is always dark grey and so that they're always horizontally-centred on my pages. I've found some documentation on [`longtable`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf), but I don't yet have the know-how to make sense of it. I'd be very grateful if someone could give me a hand. Below is some code showing where I've got to so far:

```
% Type of doc.
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}


% General packages
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{enumerate}


% Set for tables
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.95}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{array} % for extrarowheight
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}



% Start doc.
\begin{document}


% Global font settings
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}
\fontencoding{T1}
\fontfamily{ppl}
\fontsize{14}{18}
\selectfont


% Text

\chapter{Preface}

\section{Section 1}

Lots of text here.  Lots of text here.  Lots of text here.  Lots of text here.  Lots of text here.  Lots of text here.  Lots of text here.

\clearpage

\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{longtable}{|p{7.5cm}|p{7.5cm}|}
\hline

\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{Col. 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Col. 2}} \\ \hline

Text in Col 1. & Text in Col 2. \\ \hline
Text in Col 1. & Text in Col 2. \\ \hline
Text in Col 1. & Text in Col 2. \\ \hline
Text in Col 1. & Text in Col 2. \\ \hline
Text in Col 1. & Text in Col 2. \\ \hline

\hline
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Also asked on the [LaTeX community forum](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=25474).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please report the full question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! In addition to the notion that your question is cross-posted somewhere else you should elaborate your actual question also here. Links may expire, thus lessen the value of your question for future readers.

Comment: why have you loaded pslatex? (you don't want to load that ever, I wrote it:-) but that mainly makes times the default and you don't even use that you reset to ppl later.

Comment: `longtable` is centred horizontally by default, isn't it?

Comment: Hello cfr.  No it doesn't seem to centre horizontally by default.  Either way, there are a number of changes I'd like to make to all the long tables in my doc, so I'd like to know how to do such things please.

Answer (score 2):

Longtable are centred by default although you can change to left or right with `\begin{longtable}[l]`. In the example there is very little difference as the table is anyway forced to be full width by the wide `p` columns, so there is very little alignment of the table needed.

Like `tabular`, it doesn't really have any global settings for fonts and colours, although you can of course define your own macro shortcuts for forms you use often. To get a heading on a dark grey background that is repeated at a page break you can do something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}


% General packages
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{enumerate}


% Set for tables
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.3}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{array} % for extrarowheight
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}



% Start doc.
\begin{document}


% Global font settings
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}
\fontencoding{T1}
\fontfamily{ppl}
\fontsize{14}{18}
\selectfont


% Text

\chapter{Preface}

\section{Section 1}

Lots of text here.  Lots of text here.  Lots of text here.  Lots of text here.  Lots of text here.  Lots of text here.  Lots of text here.

\clearpage

\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{longtable}{|p{7.5cm}|p{7.5cm}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{darkgray}
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\color{white}\textbf{Col. 1}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\color{white}\textbf{Col. 2}} \\ \hline
\endhead
Text in Col 1. & Text in Col 2. \\ \hline
Text in Col 1. & Text in Col 2. \\ \hline
Text in Col 1. & Text in Col 2. \\ \hline
Text in Col 1. & Text in Col 2. \\ \hline
Text in Col 1. & Text in Col 2. \\ \hline

\hline
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```